# can i change oem tyre 256/40R21 105 y to 265/60R 18 or 265/70 R 16 on my mercedes ml 350

Tags: wheels

i have serious problem with the oem tyres supplied 265/40R21 y 105. These tyres are getting damaged on pothole filled roads or on a bad rough road. i was told it happens because these aer low profile tyres. i want to put rugged high profile tyres.will any of these combinations  work  265/60R 18 or 265/70 R 16. how are good year eagle 255/50R 21.106 w.

Comment: Asking how good is a particular make of tyre is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can't fit any of the alternative sized tyres without additionally changing your wheels.  Furthermore, if you reduce the diameter of your wheels, you may find that they do not fit over the brakes.

It would be helpful to know the year and trim lever of your Mercedes ML-350.  As a rule of thumb, check the alternative trim / spec versions of your particular car to see what the other OEM wheels and tyre combinations are but this won't guarantee that they'll clear your brake discs / calipers.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all a little theory (you might know this, but if someone else doesn't it can be good to have).

Let's start with a breakdown of the numbers: 
`265/40R21 y 105`

- 265 is the width in mm
- 40 the height of the tyre, in precentage of the width (so 40% of 265mm = 106mm)
- R21 (or /21 would also be common) is the tyre inner diameter in inches
- y should be a speed rating (not important for this question)
- 105 I !Think! that this is a load index (also not important now)

So first of all, just as Steve says, none of the tiers you have suggested will fit on the rims you have today (16" or 18" vs 21").

Secondly, for the tire to fit, it can't be to wide or it will rub against the inside of the wheel wells or inner fenders. (Width also need to somewhat match the width of the rims)

Now by Swedish law you have to have a tire that doesn't differ more than 5% from the original circumference. So let's do the math: c_org = 2*106 + 21*2,54*10 * pi = 2342mm, now c_16 = 2*185 + 16+2,54*10 = 2439mm and c_18 = 2435mm

So both assuming that c_org is the original size, the c_16 and c_18 differs with about 4%. So in legal terms, at least in Sweden (you'll have to check your counties rules) that would be ok.

(Remember that a 4% increase of wheel size will reduce the shown speed at your speedo with 4%)

*Personal note:* of course you should have a high profile tire on a SUV!